# What is meaning of "address: equivalent to uint160, except for the assumed interpretation and language typing."?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x

I'm reading solidity document and cannot understand the meaning of **"address: equivalent to uint160, except for the assumed interpretation and language typing."** in [the doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/abi-spec.html?highlight=abi%20spec#types)

Does anyone know what is the exactly meaning?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*uint160* is the shortest unsigned integer which can hold 20 bytes of information - Ethereum addresses are 20 bytes in hexadecimal format. So you can convert an Ethereum address directly into *uint160* and back.

What the latter part of the sentence says is that the *address* word has also a special meaning: it's a reserved keyword which implies an address used within the Ethereum network. And *uint160* doesn't have any implied information except that it's an unsigned integer number. An *address* also have some special handling in Solidity, for example you can't give a function *uint160* and implicitly cast it into an *address* - the cast has to be explicit.

Furthermore the *uint160* equivalence can be used if you need to convert from *address* to *address payable* (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#explicitness-requirements).